# Theming the output of multiple image upload widget in node create/edit form

Tags: nodes, theming

I need to theme the node create/edit page according to the user's specifications. To do so, I need to output of theme_file_widget_multiple($variables), I suppose. It gives out table format which I need to convert into grid or divs. If there is some other easier hook or function for the same thing, please suggest me.

Can anyone help out?enter image description here[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use [MYTHEME_image_widget](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.field.inc/function/theme_image_widget/7). This theme function allows you to adjust the output of the image widget.

In combination with  [MYMODULE_field_widget_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/7) and [MYMODULE_image_field_widget_process](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.field.inc/function/image_field_widget_process/7) you should be good to go.